# Minimize partition

Tags: algorithms

Given an array $A$ which has $n$ elements

> $1 \le n \le 100000$

Each $A[i]$ can have the maximum value of $w$ .

> $1 \le w \le 100000$

Partition $A$ into $k$ subsets such that each subset sum should not exceed $w$.

We need to minimize $k$.